# Choice of referent twin in twin difference model

Tags: causality, paired-data

Carlin (2005) points out that mixed effects models specifically for twin data can be simplified by calculating differences between paired clusters. This allows for modeling specifically the within cluster effects and cancelling out any between cluster effects.

http://ije.oxfordjournals.org/content/34/5/1089.short

The mixed model:

\begin{equation}
E(Y_{ij} | X_{ij}) = \beta_0 + \beta_W (X_{ij} - \bar{X}_{i\cdot}) + \beta_B\bar{X}_{i\cdot}
\end{equation}

Becomes

\begin{equation}
E(D_i^{Y}) = \beta_W D_i^{X}
\end{equation}

with $D_{i}^X = X_{i1} - X_{i2}$

The results of this analysis depends on how you code twins as 1 and 2. The author simply states, "The oldest twin is chosen as the referent [i=1] twin" without mentioning whether it is a global rule or a deliberate choice for this analysis. I think there must be some kind of causal framework aspect to this. It seems like, for some analyses (especially post-infancy), the choice of order could be different and this could give vastly different results.

How do you chose who is twin #1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see now. Because the model is constrained so that the intercept goes through 0, any permutation of sign in the differences of the response variable due to ordering discrepancy will be proportional to differences in the exposure for the same reason. Hence, it all balances out regardless of choice of twin order. You'll get the same results regardless of which twin is coded as which.